# Regex: Add .dot at every 8 words

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I need to put a dot after every 8 words. My regex is not so good:

SEARCH: `((\w+){8})`

REPLACE BY: `\1.`

Comment: What is a word for you? Only alphabetic `[a-zA-Z]`, alphanumeric `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, word character `\w`, everything that is not a space or something else?
Please, edit your question and add sample text and expected result.

Comment: @toto. simple words like this: "Return to what you don’t know and at the same time distance yourself from what you want to know, in order to maximize your chance of turning art into a way of feeling superior."

Comment: Well, what about `don't`, is it a single word or two words? Is the character `'` part of word characters? And what about `-` character? With your given text, what should be the result? Please, edit your question to insert that example, don't put it in comment.

Comment: yes @Toto, `'` should be part of word characters, not different. Also `-`  should be part of word characters, only in the case `comsi-comsa` but not  `comsi comsa`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\S+\s+){7}\S+\K`
- Replace with: `.`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
    \S+         # 1 or more non space
    \s+         # 1 or more spaces
){7}        # end group, must appear 7 times
\S+         # 1 or more non space
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: super answer, thanks again @Toto